# Is there a way to Geo-lock an Android Tablet

Tags: tablet, geolocation

We are selling our house and it has extensive automation etc.  To help the agents, I have bought a new tablet, where I can have a cut down access to the smart home - for demo purposes.  I don't really want to put a pin (or lock) on it.

I would like to be able to Geo-Lock it.  So it doesn't work, outside the house/land area.  Is there anyway I can do this, using apps is fine ?